# OAuth 2.0 gmail send message

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am trying with API REST google to connect to gmail and send a message with this API using the information in a contact form for the new message.
The documentation is not clear enough.
I use javascript.
Does anyone have any idea where he managed to do that?
thank you in advance

Comment: It would help us if you linked to the documentation and provided an example of what you consider unclear

Answer (score 0):

You should try and familiarize yourself using the [JavaScript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js). This will helps you authorize your request using OAuth 2.0. Then use [**`send()`**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send), this will send the specified message to the recipients.

Here is the [code snippet](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#examples) for sending :

```
/**
 * Send Message.
 *
 * @param  {String} userId User's email address. The special value 'me'
 * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
 * @param  {String} email RFC 5322 formatted String.
 * @param  {Function} callback Function to call when the request is complete.
 */
function sendMessage(userId, email, callback) {
  // Using the js-base64 library for encoding:
  // https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-base64
  var base64EncodedEmail = Base64.encodeURI(email);
  var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
    'userId': userId,
    'resource': {
      'raw': base64EncodedEmail
    }
  });
  request.execute(callback);
}
```

There are also references/tutorials with regards to sending messages using javascript and Gmail API.

- [Sending Emails with the Gmail JavaScript API](https://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-gmail-javascript-api/)
- [Working with the Gmail JavaScript API](https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/gmail-api-javascript-example)

You could also use [Apps Script](https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server) and deploy it as a web app then let handled the Apps script do the rest.

Hope this helps.